# pivot_wider with duplicates while keeping some unique information from each duplicate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot

I seek a solution in `dplyr`.

I have this (large) dataframe:

```
  speclib id frak mload protein
1      No R1    R   190     491
2      No R2    R   160     490
3 SpecLib R1    R   190     564
4 SpecLib R2    R   160     559
```

I have analyzed the *same* sample with two different methods (either `df$speclib == "No"` or `df$speclib == "SpecLib"`)

I need to pivot_wider or similar so each unique sample correspond to one row, while creating two columns that denote the `df$protein` corresponding to `df$speclib`.

```
  id frak mload protein_speclibNo protein_speclibSpecLib
1 R1    R   190               491                    564
2 R2    R   160               490                    559
```

I tried `pivot_wider(names_from = speclib, values_from = protein)` but I receive:

> Warning message: Values from `protein` are not uniquely identified;
> output will contain list-cols. • Use `values_fn = list` to suppress
> this warning. • Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise
> duplicates. • Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
> {data} %>%   dplyr::group_by(id, frak, mload, speclib) %>%
> dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
> dplyr::filter(n > 1L)

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(speclib = c("No", "No", "No", "SpecLib", "SpecLib"), id = c("R1", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2"), frak = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R"), mload = c(190, 190, 160, 190, 160), protein = c(490L, 491L, 490L, 564L, 559L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The issue you describe does not arise with `df` as you have it above. I added a row here and this produces the issue.

`
df <- structure(list(speclib = c("No", "No", "No", "SpecLib", "SpecLib"), 
                     id = c("R1", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2"), 
                     frak = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R"), 
                     mload = c(190, 190, 160, 190, 160), 
                     protein = c(490L, 491L, 490L, 564L, 559L)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because you have two different values for the same case for `R` `190` (`mload` = 490 or 491) The argument `values_fn` allows you to specify a function to choose which one of the several values you wanna keep. Here, keep the `max`.

This is stated in the warning message:

> • Use values_fn = {summary_fun} to summarise duplicates.

```r
pivot_wider(df, names_from = speclib, values_from = protein,
            values_fn = max)

# # A tibble: 2 × 5
#   id    frak  mload    No SpecLib
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>   <int>
# 1 R1    R       190   491     564
# 2 R2    R       160   490     559
```